# pre-fetch data before loading component with selector

Tags: angular

I have a module for a unique component with his own routingModule and resolver to pre-fetch data from backend.
in the component's ngOnInit() I get the data passed in the route to fill a form. So if I call it with it's route, It works.

The problem is I also want to be able to load it by its selector inside a component of another external module and still pre-fetch data before loading.

the natural solution I got is to do this in the ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if(comingFromRoot()) {
   this.route.data.subscribe(
     (data: {contactData: any}) => {
      ...
     }     
   );
  } else {
    this.backend.getContactData().subscribe( () => ... );
  }
}
```

is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngIf` in that case something like in your parent component html

```
<your-componenet *ngIf="data" [data]="data"></your-component>
```

In your componenet get data as input

```
  @Input() data:any;
  ngOnInit() {
      if(!data) {
      this.route.data.subscribe((data: {contactData: any}) => {
      ...
      });
   }
```

and In your parent component.ts

```
data:any;

//following in constructur or ngoninit
this.backend.getContactData().subscribe( (data) => this.data=data );
```